# Fitting to camera (perspective) an arbitrary 3D model import

Tags: unity, camera, import

Is there a general method for resizing an arbitrary 3D model imported at runtime to fit the camera boundaries (i.e. fill 80% or so) ?

For example, some 3D scanned models often do not have the model ratio properly set up so will import too small or too big. How does one make sure it's resized to fit within a normalized size or in the camera viewport (at runtime)?

For example, something like this - though it doesn't seem to work for arbitrary sized objects

```
 public void MoveCamera(GameObject g,Camera c)
    {
        Vector3 xyz = g.GetComponentInChildren<MeshFilter>().mesh.bounds.size;
        float distance = Mathf.Max(xyz.x, xyz.y, xyz.z);
        distance /= (2.0f * Mathf.Tan(0.5f * c.fieldOfView * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
        // Move camera in -z-direction; change '2.0f' to your needs
        c.transform.position = new Vector3(c.transform.position.x, c.transform.position.y, -distance * 2.0f);
    }
```

Comment: We'll need some more information or constraints, as currently the problem is under-defined. If you're using perspective projection, then the scale that fits changes with depth — the farther away from the camera we place the model, the larger it can/must be to fill the extents as you require. Aspect ratio is also important: if your camera view is wider than it is tall, do you want to fill 80% of the height (so, leaving gaps at the sides), 80% of the width (so, likely extending off-screen above and below), 80% of the pixel area (also likely to go off screen), etc?

Comment: well, so it's a mix of scale and size and camera parameters. Suppose you can place it at any location, dead center, how would you change the scale and/or size or camera parameter?

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" did you mean to accompany this code with a specific reproducible test case showing exactly how it fails? We'll have a much harder time fixing problems that you have not demonstrated.

Comment: Should the code work (?) - i found it on unity answers. Tried it with default mesh as well.

Comment: You have claimed it does not produce the outcome that you want. Since you have not told us what outcome it does produce, or how that outcome differs from the outcome you want, we are unable to evaluate this claim. (ie. **Edit your question** to demonstrate a specific case where this fails)

Comment: Well, there isn't much to show where it fails. Just camera with nothing visible in scene (either model is too big or too small for camera to see or fit)

Comment: Yep, and it is *your job* to determine which it was; was the result too big, or if it was too small (or for this code, was the translation applied to the camera too great or too little)? Tell us exactly what that output value was, for exactly what input values you provided, and what output values you expected / would have met your needs instead. We will not guess on your behalf. Give us actual specific numbers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71215446/runtime-algorithm-for-unity-editors-press-f-to-focus-on-a-gameobject

Comment: Would you like me to close this question as a cross-post, now that you've posted a second question that asks effectively the same thing?

Comment: Well, I provided a concrete example of what I'm trying to figure out how to do?

Comment: Do you know if it's more or less clear? Maybe I am just not explaining or using the right nomenclature  (?)

Comment: Your question is not unclear, it is incomplete. I've told you exactly what you need to add to your question to demonstrate how the code above is failing to meet your needs, and you have simply not done it. Your question is also somewhat inconsistent: you begin by asking how to resize the model, then show code that does not resize the model, it moves the camera. When you **edit your question** as I've been recommending, be sure to streamline it so that it asks about only one of these things.